# Update manager cannot connect to internet in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, internet, proxy, updates

Update manager and software center fail to update/install due to network connection error. Synaptic can connect, so can web browser and mail application.

I am using a proxy to connect to the internet. Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Software Centre does not use the system-wide Proxy settings, so you have to configure it separately.

The Ubuntu forums ([link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-83401.html)) suggest you need to:

- Set http_proxy, ftp_proxy and
  https_proxy variables in bash.bashrc
- Set proxy settings in
  /etc/apt/apt.conf
- Set proxy settings
  in Network Connections -> Proxy in
  System Settings

Further information can be found on launchpad: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/466142) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/545134)